# Cannot connect to remote server with no firewall and port open

Tags: postgresql, server

I have set up Postgresql on a remote server, and for some reason I cannot connect to the 5432 port on the server even after opening up the port, deactivating firewall, etc.

1. I have checked that the database is listening to all addresses with
   `listen_addresses = '*'`:

`postgresql.conf`:

[image: postgresql.conf]

`SHOW listen_addresses`:

[image: SHOW listen_addresses; in psql]

2. changed pg_hba.conf:

[image: pg_hba.conf]

3. checked that port number 5432 is open and listening with
   `netstat -nlp | grep 5432`

[image: netstat result]

4. checked that firewall is inactive with sudo `ufw status`

[image: firewall result]

and still I get Operation timed out error message after performing both

```
nc -v [ip_address] 5432
watch "nc -v [ip_address] 5432"
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to enable connection to the remote server from external network?

Comment: You have proved that it is a network problem. Stackoverflow is not the forum for those.

Comment: Additionally: text information is better shown as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - screen shots are [not a good idea](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will write the results in formatted text in the future and look into dealing with network issues with postgresql.